# C# assertion on an array

Tags: c#, arrays, assertion

I have made an assertion on an array to find specific text. But the assertion does not seem to work.

```
var a = (JArray)jObj["cast"];
Assert.AreEqual(a, "Tim");
```

It does not seem to be searching through var a

Comment: you could use the `FluentAssertions` nuget package which supports these assertions

Comment: Thanks - trying this now i get an exception, the Expected collection is empty. I am now using..                                                                                             var a = (JArray)jObj["cast"];
a.Should().Contain("character");

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the source JSON input, it's virtually impossible to say what is specifically wrong with the Assertion, but from what I can see, you should not be comparing a JArray and a string for equality.  From the [docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jarray.htm), JArray implements IList, so you might be looking for a specific elements inside that collection, or if you are looking for the token name which contains that JArray, then you might be looking for the .Value() method once you have a reference to the token of interest.